# Jenkins installed as Windows Service on 2012 Setup Jenkins URL properly?

Tags: windows, jenkins, url-rewriting

I have a question, I installed Jenkins on Windows 2012 as a windows service and by default the URL is http://localhost:8080

I want to use http://IP/Jenkins

However I am unable to get this to work.  if I set the URL to http://IP/jenkins and restart Jenkins I still can only access it via the http://ip:8080

I want a URL that is easy to remember Please help?
I have read all the other posted questions that are similar with no help has no one had to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem, edited jenkins.xml and added --httpPort=90 --prefix=/jenkins and restarted jenkins service but it still runs on http://localhost:8080